# Force line break before adding string in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
    <center>
    <input type="text" id="item">
    <button onclick="getItem()">Add to List</button> <br>
    <textarea readonly id="list"></textarea>
</body>

<script>
    function getItem() {
    document.getElementById("list").value += document.getElementById("item").value;
}
</script>

</html>
```

As you may be able to tell, I have created an "Item" textbox and a button that, when clicked, adds the content of said "Item" textbox to the "List" textarea.

What I want to know is how do I add a line break before it adds the item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("list").value += "\n" + document.getElementById("item").value;
```