# Force line break only if there is text? Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <input type="text" id="item" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('getItem').click()">
            <button id="getItem" onclick="getItem()">Add to List</button>
            <button onclick="getClearItem()">Clear</button> <hr color="gray" id="lineDivider">
            <button onclick="getClearList()">Clear List</button> <br>
        <textarea readonly id="list"></textarea>
    </center>

</body>

<script>
    function getItem() {
        if (document.getElementById("list").value == "") {
            document.getElementById("list").value += document.getElementById("item").value;
    }
        else { 
            document.getElementById("list").value += \n document.getElementById("item").value;
        }
}

    function getClearItem() {
        document.getElementById("item").value = ""
    }

    function getClearList() {
        document.getElementById("list").value = ""
    }
</script>

</html>
```

This is what I am trying to do:

You enter some text into the "item" textbox and click the "Add to list" button. Then if the "List" textarea is blank it adds the text without inserting a line break. But if there is already some text in the textarea, it inserts a linebreak and then adds the text. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or how it should even be done.

When I remove the if else statement and just use     `document.getElementById("list").value += document.getElementById("item").value;` it works. When I add the \n to that, it does not add anything to the blank field.

I apologize if my question is unclear.

Comment: You really should learn to look at the error or debug console in the browser to see when you have script errors.  Those script errors will immediately tell you when you have an error like this that is aborting your script and it will usually tell you what line the error is one and sometimes tell you what the error is.

Comment: I was waiting for this question based on your earlier question. :) And you did not copy the answer from [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471823/force-line-break-before-adding-string-in-js) correctly it seems.

Comment: Haha sorry guys, I'm new to JS entirely so I didn't realize it was just a stupid syntaax error. I'll remember the debugger from now on :D thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to quote the newlines, as in "\n"

```
document.getElementById("list").value += "\n" + document.getElementById("item").value;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4kyzrb5z/)